# how to Change the suffix in moment js from 2 hours ago to 2h

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and I am using momentjs for my date formatting

the momentjs time fromNow function returns a date like 2 hours ago

I need  it to just return 2h  instead of 2 hours

any help?

Comment: string has a replace method ...

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow/ - If you pass `true`, you can get the value without the suffix. There you can remove the "ago" and as the others mentioned you can use a replace.

Answer (score 0):

Well you achieve it with some tweaks like

```
const today = moment();
const someday = moment('2022-09-21 10:00Z');

const diff = today.diff(someday, 'hours');
```

this will return you the number only and you can, later on, append an 'h' to it like

> diff+'h';